# How to prevent the used dll reference from being removed from the project after pulling the incoming commits?

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, entity-framework, .net-core

When I pull incoming commits in the visual studio some used dlls not recognized. And shows namespace error. So I have to delete the dll and add it again to run correctly.
What's the problem? How do I can prevent the dll reference from being removed from the Visual Studio project after pulling the incoming commits?

Comment: Please provide details of the csproj file, reference, error message and more details.

Comment: Some dll has dependencies .those configure at the time of instalation .Which dll you remove and add and what is the nature of the dll

Comment: Thank you for reply, I solved this with change CopyLocal in Reference Properties. Copy Local must be `Yes` to add reference path to `myproject.csproj`  @Madushan  @LDS